# add title and description with LinkedIn share button

Tags: javascript, share, linkedin-api

I am using a simple JavaScript popup window to display a Share with LinkedIn dialog, based on the solution in this thread: [How to make a custom LinkedIn share button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10713542/how-to-make-custom-linkedin-share-button).

```
https://www.linkedin.com/cws/share?url=http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com
```

I was wondering if there is any way to add a title and description to the query string? I noticed that when you do this with the google example it automatically pulls in this information. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=http://example.com/adaptxt-beta-android&title=http://example.com/adaptxt-beta-android&summary=http://example.com/adaptxt-beta-android&source=http://example.com/adaptxt-beta-android

You mean this? LinkedIn share article script.

Comment: Is there a way to determine if the article is successfully posted or not using that share article script?

Comment: not working anymore these days

Answer (score 2):

The only parameter supported by the LinkedIn share url is `url`, so, try something like this...

```
https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url={url}
```

**[Official Microsoft LinkedIn Share API Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/plugins/share-plugin)**.  Take a look here, you'll see that LinkedIn no longer supports a `summary`, `title`, or other parameters.  Only `url`.

They *used to* support other parameters, though.  But they seemed to have changed with Microsoft's acquisition of LinkedIn.  Wished someone updated you on that?  If you are interested in a regularly maintained GitHub project that keeps track of this so you don't have to, check it out!  [Social Share URLs](https://github.com/bradvin/social-share-urls)

[image: Social Share URLs Image]