# Open Popup window using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am looking to open one aspx page (test.aspx) in two different popup windows at the same time.

what I have till now second replace first one and page recreate in first.

I think it require more clarification here so,

Basicaly I create a graph and place it in test.aspx,
and save that graph as image file. 
I put a button on test.aspx which linked with stimulsoft report and that report show pdf format of that image.
Now if i open with test.aspx it replace the image page. but I want to see both graph and pdf same time. 
One solution is I create a new blank aspx page to display report but I try avoid to add new page because it is possible to mount report on test.aspx.

The question is just to open a single POPUP window twice on same time, but may be it is posible or not. and each and every popup containing there own dynamic controls and report like mrt.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I try to use one aspx page for two different things like one show asp.net controls and second show report.

Comment: You can use https://github.com/reduardo7/xpopup

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Change the window name in your two different calls:

```
function popitup(url,windowName) {
       newwindow=window.open(url,windowName,'height=200,width=150');
       if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
       return false;
     }
```

windowName must be unique when you open a new window with same url otherwise the same window will be refreshed.

Comment: I already tried that but not working. Thanks Umesh

Comment: Add some random value in the end of the url's querystring - var noCache = '&x=' + new Date().getMilliseconds();

Comment: I accept that but it still has few issue. But I think that is best one here. Thanks Umesh

Comment: You should use eight and width in pixels.

Comment: Someone can explain to me how this answer could open a popup??? window.open will open a new tab alwaaaays.

Comment: Must provide all three parameters to `window.popup` to get the actual popup effect. Confirmed on 1/12/2024 on the latest Chrome. Using only 1 or 2 parameters will result in the "additional tab" behavior that I see brought up in the comments. Example: `window.open("https://stackoverflow.com", "taget", 'height=300px,width=300px')`

Answer (score 13):

To create a popup you'll need the following script:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function popitup(url) {
newwindow=window.open(url,'name','height=200,width=150');
if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
return false;
}


</script>
```

Then, you link to it by:

```
  <a href="popupex.html" onclick="return popitup('popupex.html')">Link to popup</a>
```

If you want you can call the function directly from document.ready also. Or maybe from another function.

Comment: thanks but I already place that script in my code. but the difference is i want to open same aspx page in 2 window popup at the same time.

Comment: You can give the url of the page and call the function twice

Comment: Yes I tryed that but it open in first window again....:(

Comment: and the important thing is second time it use to show PDF file.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by " it open in first window again"? Can you show a snapshot or something. Iused this script and it worlks fine

Comment: yes i try to open new instance of same page but want to load report when it load second. it works fine but in a same window not in another window\]

Comment: why do you have that if for `window.focus` ?  isn't better just do `window.open(url,'name','height=200,width=150').focus();` ?

Answer (score 7):

First point is- showing multiple popups is not desirable in terms of usability.

But you can achieve it by using multiple popup names

```
var newwindow;
function createPop(url, name)
{    
   newwindow=window.open(url,name,'width=560,height=340,toolbar=0,menubar=0,location=0');  
   if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
}
```

Better approach will be showing both in a single page in two different iFrames or Divs.

**Update:**

So I will suggest to create a new tab in the test.aspx page to show the report, instead of replacing the image content and placing the pdf.

Comment: No I dont face any problem to open this page for my code I don't need to use iFrames or Divs.both are working fine but if i use same page for both, second window open in first window as well but i try to keep first and open report in second page. basicly it is because of url I get the issue but looking for solution. Thankyou Wolf

Comment: I think i got your question now. Updated my answer

Comment: I am not getting how to create a tab in popup window?