# How to go to a URL using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to go to a URL using jQuery or JavaScript.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)"  onclick="javascript:goToURL()">Go To URL</a>

function goToURL(url){
// some code to go to url

}
```

I don't want to use window.location as I want to invoke this link from a popup.

New link should also open in a popup.  I also don't want to use Ajax. Just simulate href in JavaScript.

Comment: **window.location.replace** instead of  **document.location.href**. check here,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery-javascript

Comment: You can use the `window.open('URL')` ,have a look at this [window.open](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14352248/2417602) link

Answer (score 408):

```
//As an HTTP redirect (back button will not work )
window.location.replace("http://www.google.com");

//like if you click on a link (it will be saved in the session history, 
//so the back button will work as expected)
window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
```

Comment: any way to do it in a new tab?

Comment: What's the difference between `window.location.href` and `location.href`

Comment: @YahyaUddin There is no difference, window.location is the exact same object the same as location, unless it has been overridden elsewhere of cause.

Comment: @HandofC'thuhlu Is there one more recommended to use than the other. Like a best practice?

Comment: @YahyaUddin I stick to `window.location.href` just in case someone-else overrode the location variable elsewhere.

Comment: @Deekor, onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com')" -> this opens in a new tab.

Comment: As variant window.open(url, (newWindow ? '_blank' : '_self'));

Comment: @Deekor for new tab you can use  `window.open(url, '_blank');`

Answer (score 116):

why not using?

```
location.href='http://www.example.com';
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script>
    function goToURL() {
      location.href = 'http://google.it';

    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="goToURL(); return false;">Go To URL</a>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 23):

window.location is just what you need. Other thing you can do is to create anchor element and simulate click on it

```
$("<a href='your url'></a>").click();
```

Comment: Haha.. Interesting, but is there any case that this solution will be used?

Comment: Maybe if you like to add `target="_blank"`

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you have to use the anchor # to play with this. If you reverse engineer the Gmail url system, you'll find

```
https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox
https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox?compose=new
```

Everything after # is the part your want to load in your page, then you just have to chose where to load it.

By the way, using document.location by adding a #something won't refresh your page.