# set a $_GET value when option is selected

Tags: html, get

How would I set filter_branch=true and filter_branch_val=sony via $_GET  when an option is selected?

```
<select name="filter_brand">
   <option>Sony</option>
   <option>LG</option>
</select>
```

So I have something like `http://mypage.com/index.php?filter_branch=true&filter_branch_val=sony` to be used for sql query filter.

Comment: When u want to send the values as query string on change event of select box?

Comment: @fireflieslive I've posted a working code, you also need to add a new option called something like "no selection *". Otherwise you can't select the default option. Please accept answer if you are satisfied :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If java script function will work for you . please try this code

HTML

```
<select name="filter_brand" onchange="sendFilter(this.value)">
 <option>Sony</option>
 <option>Lg</option>
 <option>Samsung</option>
</select>
```

Javscript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function sendFilter(vaa)
 {
     console.log(vaa);
     window.location.href = 'product.php?  
     filter_branch_val='+vaa+'&filter_branch=true';
 }
</script>
```

Comment: Have you added: `<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>` in your <head>?

Comment: @GjertGjersund , no because here i am using just java script not jquery

Comment: Also `+vaa+` gets me an error in my IDE, not sure why though. Of course. Should have seen that. However, the post I commented is working atleast :)

Comment: If you want to see it in work go here: www.gogetit.no. I added the code to my website.

Comment: i just uplaoded the script which i posted here . http://azeezkallayi.com/demo/test/select.html its working fine here

Comment: I've come across the same problem as you, we can't select the item previously selected. Which means you need to have an option such as No selection made or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery for this. I have tested it and it is working.

Add this:

```
<head> <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script> </head>
```

**HTML**

```
<select id="myselect" name="filter_brand" onchange="javascript:goToURL()">
   <option>No selection *</option>
   <option>Sony</option>
   <option>LG</option>
</select>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
<script>
function goToURL(url){
var option = $( "#myselect option:selected" ).text();
var yoururl = "http://www.example.com/";
var url = yoururl+ "?page="+ option;
window.location.replace(url);
}
</script>
```

Try this and come back to me.
I used [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959476/how-to-go-to-a-url-using-jquery) and [This](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-get-the-text-value-of-a-selected-option/) as reference.