# CSS, HTML, JS: Open a PopUp by an OnClick function

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have downloaded an [Europe map](https://cssmapsplugin.com/5/demo/) and I need to add an `OnClick` function, that, instead of changing the color to yellow, should open a mini PopUp inside the same page, showing some info about that state.

In the custom events section, it says

> Custom functions will not be added to the automatically generated source code.
>   Add them manually to the $.CSSMap(); function options object.

So I put it in the `index.html`, but it still doesn't work. 
Can someone help?
Thanks.

Comment: I translate: i found an image, now code me my website around it, peasants!

Comment: @Zim84: Your comment made me laugh. But nevertheless, I improved the question.

Answer (score 1):

Reading from the docs:

> Custom events
>
> onClick: function(listItem){} Function function called when region is
>   clicked
>
> to prevent default click actions add the rel="nofollow" attribute to
>   the links

So you can use something like this if I'm not wrong:

```
$("#map-europe").CSSMap({
  onClick: function(item){
     //something like this...
     popitup("http://example.com?state="+item);
  }
});
//original code: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14351988/5032157
function popitup(url) {
   newwindow = window.open(url,'name','height=300,width=250');
   if (window.focus) { 
       newwindow.focus();
   }
   return false;
}
```

I was unable to test it, so answer if this doesn't works with the error so I can edit the answer.

**First edit:** If you want a lightbox and not a popup window (which I think is what you want), you can use: http://fancybox.net/

Hope it helps.