# LinkedIn social share url with parameter not possible because of redirect

Tags: linkedin-api

I've got some question about the linkedin api regarding the share link for social media.
The api (https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin) shows, disregarding the url parameter, further parameters like title or summary.
But if i call the url, for instance from the doc:
https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=http://developer.linkedin.com&title=LinkedIn%20Developer%20Network
&summary=My%20favorite%20developer%20program&source=LinkedIn

it redirects to 
https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.linkedin.com
but without parameter..

Is it a change in the linkedin api or a temporary issue? Or do I have a problem in my understanding?

Best regards
Richard

Comment: They seem to be ignoring title and summary parameters passed via URL now and using og:title from target URL instead

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make custom linkedin share button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10713542/how-to-make-custom-linkedin-share-button)

Comment: @richipg what was the solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

Much has changed with LinkedIn since it was purchased by Microsoft.  What you had used to work for `title`, etc., but no longer.  This is the only available format you're allowed to use...

```
https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url={url}
```

Source: **[Official LinkedIn Sharing Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/plugins/share-plugin)**.

The only way to have a preview of your `title`, `image`, etc., is to use `og:` tags.  Insert these within the `<head>` block of your HTML...

- `<meta property='og:title' content='Title of the article"/>`
- `<meta property='og:image' content='//media.example.com/ 1234567.jpg"/>`
- `<meta property='og:description' content='Description that will show in the preview"/>`
- `<meta property='og:url' content='//www.example.com/URL of the article" />`

Source: [**LinkedIn Developer Docs: Making Your Website Shareable on LinkedIn**](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/46687/making-your-website-shareable-on-linkedin?lang=en).

And, if you want to be sure that you did everything right, insert your website's URL into [**LinkedIn Post Inspector**](https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/).