# Linkedin share-link wrong

Tags: php, wordpress, linkedin-api

I'm setting up my own social share box, but I'm having trouble using the linkedin-share option.
The content inside the link is passed in through php, but I think there's an error in my code

When I try to manually change the article url inside the share-url, it works fine, but my generated link won't work.

This is what i wrote inside my code:

> `mini=true&url=<?php echo $url;?>&title=<?php echo $title; ?>&summary=<?php echo $excerpt;?>&source=dfib.net"`

and this is how it outputs in the browser:

> `https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle/?mini=true&url=http://dfib-nieuw.test/attentia-jobsite/&title=Attentia%20jobsite&summary=Hoe%20kan%20je%20deze%20doelgroep%20beter%20aanspreken%20dan%20met%20een%20aantrekkelijke%20website%20die%20alle%20job-%20en%20carri%C3%A8re-info%20overzichtelijk%20weergeeft?&source=dfib.net`

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What makes you think anything was wrong to begin with?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a custom LinkedIn share button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10713542/how-to-make-a-custom-linkedin-share-button)

Comment: When I open the link, it gives an error in Linkedin

Answer (score 0):

Look at the URL you are sharing:

```
...&url=http://dfib-nieuw.test....
```

`.test` *is not* a valid [Top Level Domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains#T), so you cannot test with that.

Typically, if you want to have a test URL, use `example.com`, for instance, this URL works perfectly for me...

https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.revoltlib.com

Source: **[Official Microsoft Linkedin Share Plugin Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/plugins/share-plugin)**.