# Share post on LinkedIn with React Native

Tags: react-native, linkedin-api

I have an app built in react-native in which I need to share a post on LinkedIn with predefined content.

I used 'react-native-share' for sharing content on LinkedIn but It's not working. How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Linking from react native

```js
import { Linking } from 'react-native';
```

and then you can use

```js
Linking.openURL("https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&summary=youtube&title=f1&url=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ");
```

you can found more info here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10737122/6125249

Comment: This is the correct answer, it works for me on "react-native": "0.71.5". The only problem is that summary and title don't work. So it should be: 
`Linking.openURL("https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ");`

Answer (score 4):

***LinkedIn supports only one parameter being passed to it, and that is the `url` parameter.***  It will look like this...

```
https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url={url}
```

Source: **[Official LinkedIn Sharing Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/plugins/share-plugin)**.

The following parameters ***will not work***: `summary`, `title`, `source`, etc..  Anything besides `url`.

To share to LinkedIn, just make a `<a href>` element that points to an above formatted-URL, and make absolutely sure to do URL-encoding on your `{url}`.

You probably want to share `title` and `summary`, though, based on the accepted answer.  You cannot do that using `GET`-data, ***BUT*** you can do that using `og:` tags.

- `<meta property='og:title' content='Title of the article"/>`
- `<meta property='og:image' content='//media.example.com/ 1234567.jpg"/>`
- `<meta property='og:description' content='Description that will show in the preview"/>`
- `<meta property='og:url' content='//www.example.com/URL of the article" />`

Source: **[LinkedIn Developer Docs: Making Your Website Shareable on LinkedIn](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/46687/making-your-website-shareable-on-linkedin?lang=en)**.

In case you are uncertain that you've followed the LinkedIn documentation correctly to make a share URL, you can test your page's URL to see how it will look when shared here: **[LinkedIn Post Inspector](https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/)**.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `react-native-share`. I have used it in one of my application.

```js
const shareOptions = {
  title: 'Share via',
  message: `Hello,  ${description}`,
  subject: 'Subject,
  url: "data:image/png;base64," + base64Data,
  showAppsToView: false,
  filename: 'test',
};
Share.open(shareOptions).then(res => {
  console.log(res)
}).catch(e => {
  console.log(e)
});
```

**Note**: It would be greater if you can share your code.

Comment: You should mention that `react-native-share` does not support LinkedIn image sharing on iOS