# Have linkedin deprecated the share-offsite URL sharing method or is it just broken?

Tags: linkedin-api, sharing

A few [stackoverflow questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10713542/how-to-make-a-custom-linkedin-share-button) make reference to the widely used method of using

`https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url={url}`

to let users share content from your site to their linkedin pages, but this results in a "something went wrong" error from linkedin or just the linkedin header logo on a blank page when used with any URL, percent encoded or otherwise.

The developer docs point to an [oauth2 method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/share-on-linkedin?context=linkedin/consumer/context) of sharing, but that's total overkill for a share button on a website.

Was there an announcement? I can't find any and lots of websites (Youtube, NYT, ABC(AU)) are currently using this method of sharing including, ironically the very Microsoft [developer doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/share-on-linkedin?context=linkedin/consumer/context) that instructs you about oauth2 sharing.

Answer (score 3):

Issue looks to be fixed now and the linkedin share is working again.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, that method is still a viable way to share to LinkedIn. That error message and this issue seem to be impacting major websites so it appears that something has broken on LinkedIn's side of things. I have been unable to find any acknowledgement of the issue but can attest my users started noticing it yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same problem today and found this question and this thread.

In our case it was because we switched our CDN and webservers from minimum TLS version v1.2 to v1.3 - not a problem for all modern browsers, but obviously a problem for LinkedIn :-(
Reverting the minimum requirement back to TLS v1.2 solved the issue, the share-offsite URL works again.

This is a also bad surprise because the LinkedIn Post Inspector (see https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/ ) didn't come up with an information or warning. It seems to be fine with TLS v1.3.

And one final note:
Using "{url}" instead of {url} as one comment says does not seem to make a difference.

Comment: I'm currently experiencing this issue, regardless of what I do. Thanks for the link to the Post Inspector though. Really helpful thing to add to my proverbial toolbox.

Answer (score -1):

Issue is fixed for me

If you still have an error check if you don't have
this :
`https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url="{url}"`

instead of this :

`https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url={url}`